# switch dark mode like whatsapp/slack etc

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-darkmode

I know switching dark mode on android programmatically is easy with below code.

```
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
```

I want to know how to do it like whatsapp/slack which won't restart the app. User will still be in preferences fragment and mode changes there right away. If I try above line, my activity is recreated and first fragment is launched but not preference fragment.

How to handle it the way they are handling it?

Comment: Fix your activity and fragments to survive activity recreation without state loss

Answer (score 0):

Put in the manifest `android:configChanges="...|uiMode|..."` for that activity
and use a day/night theme, doing so, the switch is automatic and with 0 lines of code